# Errors in my Bootstrap html file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following js links:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-5i/mQ300M779N2OVDrl16lbohwXNUdzL/R2aVUXyXWA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
```

I am getting the errors listed in the screenshot. Please help me know why.

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knKsE.jpg)

Comment: you are missing jquery file

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the jQuery 
please add jQuery in head tag like this.

```
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, it worked fine now, could you please explain? what is the difference between the jquery line you suggested the one was already listed in my code? the very first one, because that is also a jquery lib.